# Add some html and php codes bottom of wordpress post content

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to add some html and php codes at the bottom of wordpress post content, I know that with this function code I can add some content at the bottom of post content:-

```html
   add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_before' , 20 );
function add_before( $content ) {
  $custom_content .= '<div></div>'; 
    $content = $content . $custom_content;
  return $content;
}
```

Here is my codes that I want to insert at the bottom of the post content, how can I merge above code with this to works fine:-

```html
<script src="http://mlmarketing.ir/wp-content/themes/mlmarketingv2/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mlmarketing.ir/wp-content/themes/mlmarketingv2/js/jquery.hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://mlmarketing.ir/wp-content/themes/mlmarketingv2/js/jquery.tab.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
document.getElementById("copyButton2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("copyTarget2"), "msg");
});

function copyToClipboardMsg(elem, msgElem) {
   var succeed = copyToClipboard(elem);
    var msg;
    if (!succeed) {
        msg = "این ویژگی در مرورگر شما پشتیبانی نمی شود. لطفا از کلیدهای ترکیبی Ctrl + C استفاده نمایید."
    } else {
        msg = "لینک کوتاه این مطلب در کلیپ بورد شما کپی شد"
    }
    if (typeof msgElem === "string") {
        msgElem = document.getElementById(msgElem);
    }
    msgElem.innerHTML = msg;
    setTimeout(function() {
        msgElem.innerHTML = "";
    }, 5000);
}

function copyToClipboard(elem) {
   // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
        }
        target.textContent = elem.textContent;
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);
    
    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
       succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }
    
    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = "";
    }
    return succeed;
}

  });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
         $('#tab-container').easytabs();
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
div#preload{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById('preload').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
<div id="preload">
    
<?php if ( get_field('show') ) : ?>
<div id="tab-container" class='tab-container'>
<ul class='etabs'>
<?php if ( get_field('download_links') ) : ?>
<li class='tab dl-color'><a href="#tabs1-dl">لینک دانلود</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( get_field('forum_link') ) : ?>
<li class='tab forum-color'><a href="#tabs1-forum">لینک در انجمن</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( get_field('share') ) : ?>
<li class='tab share-color'><a href="#tabs1-share">اشتراک گذاری</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( get_field('info') ) : ?>
<li class='tab info-color'><a href="#tabs1-info">توضیحات</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( get_field('reference') ) : ?>
<li class='tab reference-color'><a href="#tabs1-reference">مرجع</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( get_field('shortlink') ) : ?>
<li class='tab shortlink-color'><a href="#tabs1-shortlink">لینک کوتاه</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>

<li class='tab barchasb-color'><a href="#tabs1-barchasb">برچسب ها</a></li>


</ul>



<div class='panel-container'>

<?php if ( get_field('download_links') ) : ?>
<div id="tabs1-dl">
<h3>لینک (های) دانلود</h3><br/>
<?php if ( get_field('dl_info1') ) : ?>
<img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/dl_icon.png">
<?php echo get_field('dl_info1');?>  
<a href="<?php echo get_field('dl_link1');?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_field('dl_name1');?></a> |  <img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/size_icon.png"> حجم: <?php echo get_field('dl_size1');?><br/>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( get_field('dl_info2') ) : ?>
<img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/dl_icon.png">
<?php echo get_field('dl_info2');?>  
<a href="<?php echo get_field('dl_link2');?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_field('dl_name2');?></a> |  <img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/size_icon.png"> حجم: <?php echo get_field('dl_size2');?><br/>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( get_field('dl_info3') ) : ?>
<img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/dl_icon.png">
<?php echo get_field('dl_info3');?>  
<a href="<?php echo get_field('dl_link3');?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_field('dl_name3');?></a> |  <img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/size_icon.png"> حجم: <?php echo get_field('dl_size3');?><br/>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( get_field('dl_info4') ) : ?>
<img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/dl_icon.png">
<?php echo get_field('dl_info4');?>  
<a href="<?php echo get_field('dl_link4');?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_field('dl_name4');?></a> | <img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/size_icon.png"> حجم: <?php echo get_field('dl_size4');?><br/>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( get_field('dl_info5') ) : ?>
<img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/dl_icon.png">
<?php echo get_field('dl_info5');?>  
<a href="<?php echo get_field('dl_link5');?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_field('dl_name5');?></a> | <img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/size_icon.png"> حجم: <?php echo get_field('dl_size5');?><br/>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( get_field('dl_info6') ) : ?>
<img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/dl_icon.png">
<?php echo get_field('dl_info6');?>  
<a href="<?php echo get_field('dl_link6');?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_field('dl_name6');?></a> | <img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/size_icon.png"> حجم: <?php echo get_field('dl_size6');?><br/>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( get_field('dl_info7') ) : ?>
<img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/dl_icon.png">
<?php echo get_field('dl_info7');?>  
<a href="<?php echo get_field('dl_link7');?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_field('dl_name7');?></a> | <img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/size_icon.png"> حجم: <?php echo get_field('dl_size7');?><br/>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( get_field('dl_info8') ) : ?>
<img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/dl_icon.png">
<?php echo get_field('dl_info8');?>  
<a href="<?php echo get_field('dl_link8');?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_field('dl_name8');?></a> | <img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/size_icon.png"> حجم: <?php echo get_field('dl_size8');?><br/>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( get_field('dl_info9') ) : ?>
<img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/dl_icon.png">
<?php echo get_field('dl_info9');?>  
<a href="<?php echo get_field('dl_link9');?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_field('dl_name9');?></a> | <img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/size_icon.png"> حجم: <?php echo get_field('dl_size9');?><br/>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( get_field('dl_info10') ) : ?>
<img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/dl_icon.png">
<?php echo get_field('dl_info10');?>  
<a href="<?php echo get_field('dl_link10');?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_field('dl_name10');?></a> | <img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/images/size_icon.png"> حجم: <?php echo get_field('dl_size10');?><br/>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo get_field('download_links'); ?>
</div><?php endif; ?>



<?php if ( get_field('forum_link') ) : ?><div id="tabs1-forum">
<h3>لینک مطلب در انجمن</h3><br/>
به منظور بحث و گفتگو در مورد این مطلب، می توانید به تاپیک آن در تالار گفتمان مراجعه نمایید:<br/><br/><div style="align:center; border: 2px solid #FFA459; border-radius: 8px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color: #FFDAC7; width:auto; height:20px; text-align:center; padding: 5px; font-size:16px;">
<a href="<?php echo get_field('forum_link');?> " target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
</div><?php endif; ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=600px,width=850px,top=70px,left=270px, resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')}
</script>

<?php if ( get_field('share') ) : ?><div id="tabs1-share">
<h3>اشتراک گذاری این مطلب در شبکه های اجتماعی</h3><br/>
با به اشتراک گذاشتن این مطلب، فرصت دیدن مطالب مورد علاقه ی خود را به دوستانتان هدیه دهید...!<br/>
هم اکنون می توانید این مطلب را توسط شبکه های اجتماعی زیر به اشتراک بگذارید<br/><br/>
<div class="social">

<div class="socialicons"><a class="telegram" href="JavaScript:newPopup('https://telegram.me/share/url?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>')" title="ارسال به تلگرام">تلگرام</a></div>

<div class="socialicons"><a class="twitter" href="JavaScript:newPopup('https://twitter.com/home?status=Reading: <?php the_permalink(); ?>')" title="این مطلب را توئیت کن !">Twitter</a></div>

<div class="socialicons"><a  class="facebook" href="JavaScript:newPopup('https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>')" title="این مطلب را در فیسبوک شیر کنید !">Facebook</a></div>

<div class="socialicons"><a  class="google-plus" href="JavaScript:newPopup('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>')" title="این مطلب را در گوگل پلاس منتشر کنید !">Google+</a></div>

<div class="socialicons"><a  class="cloob" href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://www.cloob.com/share/link/add?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>')" title="این مطلب را در کلوب منتشر کنید !">کلوب</a></div>

<div class="socialicons"><a  class="facenama" href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://facenama.com/links/?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>')" title="این مطلب را در فیس نما منتشر کنید !">فیس نما</a></div>


<div class="socialicons"><a  class="reddit" href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;title=<?php the_title(); ?>')" title="این مطلب را در Reddit منتشر کن !">Reddit</a></div>

<div class="socialicons"><a  class="stumbleupon" href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;title=<?php the_title(); ?>')" title="این مطلب را در Stumble it منتشر کن !">Stumble it</a></div>

<div class="socialicons"><a  class="digg" href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://digg/submit?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;title=<?php the_title(); ?>')" title="این مطلب را در Digg this! منتشر کنید !">Digg This !</a></div>

<div class="socialicons"><a  class="linkedin" href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;title=<?php the_title(); ?>&amp;url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>')" title="این مطلب را در لینکدین منتشر کنید !">Share on LinkedIn</a></div>

<div class="socialicons"><a  class="pinterest" href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&media=<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); echo $url; ?>')" title="این مطلب را در Pinterest منتشر کنید !">Pinterest</a></div>

<div class="socialicons"><a  class="delicious" href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://del.icio.us/post?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;title=<?php the_title(); ?>')" title="این مطلب را در Del.icio.us منتشر کنید !">Del.icio.us</a></div>


</div>
<div align="center">با اشتراک گذاری این مطلب، دوستان خود را از آن آگاه سازید</div>
</div><?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( get_field('reference') ) : ?><div id="tabs1-reference">
<h3>معرفی مرجع(های) این مطلب</h3><br/>
<?php echo get_field('reference'); ?>
</div><?php endif; ?>



<?php if ( get_field('info') ) : ?><div id="tabs1-info">
<h3>توضیحاتی پیرامون این مطلب</h3><br/>
<?php echo get_field('info'); ?>
</div><?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( get_field('shortlink') ) : ?><div id="tabs1-shortlink">
<h3>لینک کوتاه به این مطلب</h3><br/><div id="copyTarget2" style="font-family:'time new roman'; align:center; border: 2px solid #9E66E8; border-radius: 15px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color: #D9BDFF; width:450px; height:26px; text-align:center; padding: 5px; font-size:20px;">
<?php echo get_field('shortlink'); ?></div><button id="copyButton2" class="action-button-copy shadow-copy animate-copy green-copy">کپی</button><div id="msg" class="copymsg"></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div id="tabs1-barchasb">
<h3>فهرست برچسب ها برای این مطلب:</h3><br/>
        <?php if(get_the_tags()) {
                ?><div style="float:right;"><img src="http://mlmarketing.ir/wp-content/themes/bazar2/images/tags.png"></div>
                <?php the_tags( '<div class="entry-tag-links"><span>' . __( '' ) . '</span>', '', '</div>' ); ?><?php
            }
        ?> 
</div>

</div> </div>
<?php endif; ?>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP code, and you want to run it within an HTML document, you simply use `<?php` to indicate the beginning of the PHP, and `?>` to indicate its end.  For example, with your code...

```
<?php

    add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_before' , 20 );
    function add_before( $content ) {
    $custom_content .= '<div></div>'; 
    $content = $content . $custom_content;
    print($content);

?>

<div class='panel-container'>
```

I changed your `return()` statement, which is traditionally associated with a function declaration, to a simple `print()` statement, to display the `$content` variable.

Make sure to place this PHP at the point in your HTML where you want the results of the PHP to display.  This was not indicated in your post, but I'm sure you'll have some idea.